# Sitecore Client Session - Checking programmatically if a client has shut down browser window

Tags: session, client, sitecore, sitecore7

I need to check programatically, if the client Session of a Sitecore User still continues or not.

I have read, that Sitecore assigns a Sitecore user ticket to every user accessing a Sitecore Client application. Sitecore Client user session is kept alive until the browser is closed. 
So a users client session and server session are different things. When a user shuts down the browser, the client session ends, but the server session continues for some time. (until a session timeout ends the session)

Can anyone tell me how I can check the status of the user ticket programmatically?

Practically, the question comes down to : How can I check in code behind, if a Sitecore User has shut down the browser or not?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

> Sitecore.Web.Authentication.DomainAccessGuard.Sessions.Where(x=>x.UserName=="currentUser")